# Are there any notification services I can use for my site?

Tags: php, email, notifications

I am building a site that will allow notifications/alerts defined by the user. I have them setup based on the email address the user provides, however they stopped working for gmail accounts. Apparently, my IP address was black listed by google. I have sent them  a request to remove me from the black lists they use, but they haven't responded. I sent it over a month ago. I have read through their "ways to not get black listed" documentation, but it doesn't really help me. I have explained to google that the notifications/alerts only go out if the user requests them.

My question is are there any services that I can use to get around this (meaning services that I can send the notification through and have it forwarded to the correct email addresses)? Basically, I want to be able to send an email to any email provider, so I can view it on the computer or get an email alert on my phone.

Lastly, I do not have mail setup on my ubuntu server. I send the notifications using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending a lot of emails that way, it is pretty easy to get flagged for spam, especially if you are on a shared host.

Sending emails from the PHP `mail()` function works ok for a few test email that you can go and look for in the spam folder, but if you need any sort of serious deliverability, it is always best to subcontract that to a specialist company.

Some of the most well known include [Postmarkapp](http://postmarkapp.com), [Mailgun](http://mailgun.net) and [Mailjet](http://mailjet.com) as well as those already mentioned ([Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/))

Trust me, these guys will make sure they do not get blacklisted, and have the resources and the contacts to get their servers removed from the blacklists if it ever occurs.

**(Disclaimer: I work for mailjet)**

Comment: Amazon SES is the best buy, but they don't support DKIM!

Comment: jfoucher, thanks for the response. I have looked into mailjet and it seems to fit my needs the most. I will not be sending that much email, so the free plan is enough for me right now. I'll upgrade if I need to.

Answer (score 0):

There's no *answer* to this question.

Nonetheless, I use and recommend [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com). They have a solid free tier and an excellent, well-documented library for PHP. Using such a service will likely mitigate the problems you described.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of companies that will provide managed SMTP services.  Two of the more popular are

- [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/)
- [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)

Staying off of email blacklists is an incredibly complex topic.  Things to keep in mind, if you do it yourself, include:

- Always send from the same IP or IP range
- Make sure nobody *else* sends from your IP (problem with shared hosts)
- Make sure you have a [PTR record](http://www.spamstopshere.com/blog/2008/05/13/dns-problems-affecting-e-mail-delivery-ptr-records/)
- Only send solicited email
- Provide an effective opt out
- Use a meaningful subject line so people *remember* they asked for the email
- Don't send too many emails at once to a single domain (some rate limit you)

and if you are very serious about deliverability and have a solid budget

- Use [Return Path](http://www.returnpath.net/)